# Checking custom hotkeys/keystrokes using a low level keyboard hook

Tags: c#, enums, bit-manipulation, keyboard-hook

I am going to explain very minimaly because my other post seemed not to have been really clear.

I am working on an application that you will be able to add a custom hotkey and uppon triggered, it will do something (doesnt matter). You may say "RegisterHotKey" from the top of your head, but this, unfortunatelly, does not help me at all. The User32 dll's RegisterHotKey does not allow multiple non-modifier keys into a hotkey, eg:

```
RegisterHotKey(someWindowHandle, someHotkeyId, MOD_SHIFT, K_A); // Shift + A: ok!
RegisterHotKey(someWindowHandle, someHotkeyId, MOD_SHIFT | MOD_ALT, K_A); // Shift + Alt + A: 2 modifiers, ok!
RegisterHotKey(someWindowHandle, someHotkeyId, MOD_SHIFT, K_A | K_B); // Shift + A + B: not possible!
```

There are some other system hotkeys that cant be "overriden", but thats not the case either.

For this to work, I created a C++ dll to hook the keyboard and send the data to my C# Windows Forms application using SendNotifyMessage() calls. The data is sent and received in my form's WndProc flawlessly.

The keystroke class is as follows:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Input;

// Usage: Keystroke k = new Keystroke(Key.LShift, Key.A, Key.B)
public class Keystroke
{
    public List<Key> Keys { get; private set; };

    public Keystroke(params Key[] keys)
    {
        Keys = new List<Key>(keys);
    }
}
```

As we can see, this is a very simple snippet. Basically, a hotkey/keystroke can be composed by ANY key combination, even by modifier keys only (Shift + Alt, for example).

The keyboard events are dispatched in my WndProc in the following way:

```
public class MainForm : Form
{
    List<Keystroke> customHotkeys;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == LowLevelKeyboardHook.Message)
        {
            WinAPI.KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT keyboardHook = (WinAPI.KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(WinAPI.KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));

            switch (m.WParam.ToInt32())
            {
                case WinAPI.WM_KEYDOWN:
                case WinAPI.WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
                    DispatchKeyDownMessage(keyboardHook);
                    break;
                case WinAPI.WM_KEYUP:
                case WinAPI.WM_SYSKEYUP:
                    // ...
                    break;
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    private void DispatchKeyDownMessage(WinAPI.KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT keyboardHook)
    {
        // Convert the key code into a System.Windows.Input.Key enum value
        Key key = KeyInterop.KeyFromVirtualKey(keyboardHook.vkCode);

        foreach (Keystroke keystroke in customHotkeys)
        {
            if (keystroke.Keys.Contains(key))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Woot! Some hotkey wraps this key.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above approach does work, but this, however, doesnt seem to have the best performance. Since we're dealing with global system hooks, the messages have to be dispatched very quickly. For this, I thought about adding some sort of bitwise flags technique in the keystroke and the "keystroke.Keys.Contains(key)" wouldnt be needed anymore, speeding up things. Something **LIKE** this:

```
public class Keystroke
{
    public List<Key> Keys { get; private set; } 
    public Key Flags { get; private set; }

    public Keystroke(params Key[] keys)
    {
        Keys = new List<Key>(keys);

        foreach (Key key in keys)
        {
            Flags |= key;
        }
    }
}

// Usage: bool containsK = (someKeystroke.Flags & Key.W) == Key.W;
```

As we already know, the System.Windows.Input.Key enum does not have the [Flags] attribute. I could, however, instead use the System.Windows.Forms.Keys enum, but still, as stated in the docs, we couldnt use the values for combined bitwise operations, because they are not mutually exclusive: [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx).

To solve the flags problem, I created this class:

```
public class Flagger<T> where T : struct
{
    private static Dictionary<int, ulong> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, ulong>();

    static Flagger()
    {
        int indexer = 0;

        // Since values can be duplicated, we use names instead
        foreach (String name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)))
        {
            ulong value = 1UL << indexer++; // 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16...

            Console.WriteLine("{0} key now corresponds to the value {1}", name, value);

            dictionary.Add(name.GetHashCode(), value); 
        }
    }

    private ulong flags;

    public void Add(T value)
    {
        // Create hash only once for both checkup and storation
        int hash = value.ToString().GetHashCode();

        if (Check(hash))
        {
            ulong flag = dictionary[hash];

            flags &= flag;
        }
    }

    public void Remove(T value)
    {
        // Create hash only once for both checkup and storation
        int hash = value.ToString().GetHashCode();

        if (Check(hash))
        {
            ulong flag = dictionary[hash];

            flags &= ~flag;
        }            
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tests whether a value has already been added or not
    /// </summary>
    public bool Check(T value)
    {
        int hash = value.ToString().GetHashCode();

        return Check(hash);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Quick checkup because no hash needs to be computed
    /// </summary>
    private bool Check(int hash)
    {
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(hash))
        {
            ulong flag = dictionary[hash];

            return (flags & flag) == flag;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Finally, we are now stuck at the "ulong value = 1UL << indexer++" part. Since the Key enum contains like 200+ values, we would have "ulong value = 1UL << 200" for the 200th iteration and this results in a super giant long number that exceeds the ulong limit, resulting in duplicated values. Run the code below and youll notice it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} generated {1}", i, 1UL << i);
}
```

How could I solve the above problem? Thanks for your time.

Comment: C# != C++. The languages are not synonymous just because they both start with the same letter. Tags here have specific meaning, and shouldn't just be added randomly because they sound familiar. Add only tags that are actually relevant to your question. If you're not sure, read the tag description. If you're still not sure, don't add the tag; if it's needed, someone here will add it for you. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite I know theyre different languages. I am not sure if you took your time to read the whole post or just the tags, but I did specify where they have been used (C++ for the dll and C# for the form application, as you can see above). If you meant my problem is completely related to c# and not to c++ (since the dll does its job pretty well), then I have to tell you that a solution in c++ could be accomplished as well (if someone comes up with one, of course).

Comment: Your question is either about code in the application or code in the DLL; neither of  them is simultaneously written in both languages, are they? If not, then only a single tag applies, because your question is about the code in that language. Ergo, a single language tag applies to the question. And yes, I read it. Other than stating the DLL is written in C++, there is nothing related to C++ in the question - you even state the DLL is working flawlessly.

Comment: @pid What is a "chord"? A C++ dll has been used in order to hook the keyboard. Like I said, you can not register keystrokes (RegisterHotKey calls) such as "Shift + A + B + C" (multiple non-modifier keys). The application is supposed to let the user create a keystroke containing a combination of ANY key (even composed by modifier keys only: Shift + Alt, for example).  If you know a C# function that lets you create global hotkeys with multiple NON-MODIFIER keys (the "Shift + A + B + C" example), please let me know!

Comment: I'm not *pid*, but a *chord* is a multi-key combination (picture a piano, with multiple keys being struck simultaneously, or a guitar with multiple strings being pressed down on the frets as you strum it). I'm highly doubtful that what you want to do is possible; non-modifier keys typically arrive sequentially and not together, so a Ctrl+A+C would arrive as Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C.

Comment: @KenWhite I see. They do arrive sequentially, but thats not a problem. Once recognized which "chord" a key belongs to, I can check the key state of the other keys from that "chord". If they are all down, then a hotkey has just been triggered.